# Is it possible to define a jsx tree of a render-prop return value in Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, jsx

I have a React Component for a Library.

It´s a Table and i give Header and Body over a render-prop to the Table Component. The reason is i need to take a ref to header.

So i want do force the user of this Component library to give 1 Header and 1 Body Element as return Value. Of course this is not possible so i want that the user gives this as return value:

```
<>
  <TableHeader>
    ...
  </TableHeader>
  <TableBody>
    ...
  </TableBody>
</>
```

At this time i have this in Interface:

```
export interface ITableProperty {
  /** Component className */
  className?: string;
  /** Table Content */
  children: (headerRef: RefObject<HTMLTableSectionElement>) => ReactElement;
}
```

This is the usage of Table in a lightweight Version:

```
    <Table>
      {headerRef => {
        return (
          <>
            <TableHeader ref={headerRef}>
              <TableHeaderCell title="Wsakdjflkj Zdcnsmni" colId="1" />
              <TableHeaderCell title="WW" colId="2" />
              <TableHeaderCell title="Test letzte" colId="3" />
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              <TableBodyRow rowId="1">
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 1</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 2</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 3</TableBodyCell>
              </TableBodyRow>
              <TableBodyRow rowId="2">
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 1sadfsdfasdfsad</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>
                  <Text text="Zelle 2asdfsadfsadfasjdfhkjasdhfkjhasdlkjfhaskdjhf" monospace />
                </TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 3asdfasdfasdf</TableBodyCell>
              </TableBodyRow>
              <TableBodyRow rowId="3">
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 1</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 2</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 3</TableBodyCell>
              </TableBodyRow>
              <TableBodyRow rowId="4">
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 1</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 2</TableBodyCell>
                <TableBodyCell>Zelle 3</TableBodyCell>
              </TableBodyRow>
            </TableBody>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Table>
```